# can't figure out where the token comes from

Tags: python-requests

I'm trying to automate the interaction with a site https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru/search/index. After clicking the "find" button, the client sends a post request with a token.

For example, I'm looking for the number 2021-006-095480-983, I press find ('найти' button) and a token like '03AGdBq27GK8gPgpSfEfID-4Trqm3DI6-PXPSr5W48lg1Y0...' is sent to the post-request

I can't figure out where the token comes from and what parameters to pass in the r = requests.post("https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru/search/index", data={????}") to find the number 2021-006-095480-983?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.